# .First()' could not be translated in EFCore 3

Tags: linq, group-by, ef-core-3.1

Is there a decent work around to using .First() in Group By queries on Linq using EF Core 3.1?

Here is an example of a query reading from SQL

```
    var test = from r in dc.Role
                join f in dc.Role_User on r.RoleID equals f.RoleID
                group f by r.RoleID into g
                select new
                {
                    RoleID = g.Key,
                    SampleUserID = g.First().UserID,
                };
```

This query gives the error:

> The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:.....  .First()' could
> not be translated.

Performing the group by in a separate query and then joining on it does not seem to work.

Casting to IEnumerable might work, but for big tables it will cause performance issues bring the data to the client. IQueryable is preferred.

Comment: If this is MSSQL I don't think there's a translation for `FIRST` - try `Min` (or `Max`) instead

Comment: @AviadP. yes it is MSSQL. Min + Max are doing the same. ".Min()' could not be translated"

Comment: @CameronCastillo, `Min` should work. You are doing something wrong. `g.Min(x => x.UserID)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, the link you provided in your first comment does work, thanks

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Your last comment applies. That is actually correct and working. I have tried "g.Min().UserID".  But g.Min(x => x.UserID) is the answer.

Comment: I know that `Min` should work. But remember this solution for cases when you need first record of the group.

Answer (score 0):

**You can below code to get UserID using First().**

```
var test = from r in dc.Role join f in dc.Role_User on r.RoleID equals f.RoleID
group f by r.RoleID into g
Select new {
RoleID=g.Key,
GroupingData = g
};
var res = test.Select(t=>new {
RoleID=t.RoleID,
SampleUserID=t.GroupingData.First().UserID
}
```

In this Flow, the grouping is performed in the initial query and stored as group data in the test. And from the second query, we get the UserID.

Comment: Sensible suggestion. But also gives error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (r.RoleID), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Role_User
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core